# How to reduce ico container size?

Tags: size, containers, favicon, ico

Icon sets keep coming out huge, is this standard? The files within the ico container are very small.  Is there anything I can do to reduce the file size of the icon set?

icoconvert.com -- 
multi-image to one icon, 6 very small files, ico came out to 135k!!

ImageMagick -- 
convert.exe image-16.png image-32.png fancy.ico -- 
individual file sizes total 1.5k, ico size 5.3k!

-- convert.exe sfp-16.png sfp-32.png sfp-48.png sfp-64.png sfp.ico -- 
4 individual file sizes tiny, largest is 835 bytes, ico file size 31.2k!

While ImageMagick obviously did a better job than icoconvert as far as bucket size goes, still it seems like it is using a moving van to hold what should fit in a standard envelope.  New project is counting every byte for mobile-first dev data considerations.

Any help please?

Thank you,
Beth

Comment: Gimp also saved last grouping of files at 31.2k.  File total is 2.301k.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the ICO format itself.

Instead of focusing on the `favicon.ico` file, a workaround is to [enable GZip compression for `.ico` files in the HTTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22589277/499917).