# How to get imagemagick to create a favicon less than 15k

Tags: imagemagick, favicon, imagemagick-convert, ico

I'm using ImageMagick's `convert` command to combine 3 different sized icons (16, 32, 48 pixels square, repsective) into a single `favicon.ico`.

```
$ convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-7 Q16 x86_64 2015-07-06 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC OpenMP
Delegates: bzlib freetype jng jpeg png tiff xml zlib

$ convert 16.png 32.png 48.png favicon.ico
```

The three files are tiny, as I've already run them through ImageAlpha and ImageOptim:

```
$ ls -alh *.png 
-rw-r--r--   1 user  staff   219B Mar 20 11:46 16.png
-rw-r--r--   1 user  staff   344B Mar 20 11:46 32.png
-rw-r--r--   1 user  staff   469B Mar 20 11:44 48.png
```

However the output file created by ImageMagick is 15K

```
$ ls -alh favicon.ico 
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff    15K Mar 20 12:01 favicon.ico
```

Similarly, when I provide my 3 png images to the the free online service at [icoconvert.com](http://icoconvert.com/Multi_Image_to_one_icon/), the `output.ico` file generated is also 15K.

**Why is the generated file so needlessly huge, and is there another way to get a smaller resulting ico file?**

Comment: How about sharing your icons so folks can help you?

Comment: I'm not sure it has anything to do with my specific icons, as mentioned in the answers below, so providing my own icons here would really only dilute this question.

Comment: As you wish, but I would say a good 10-20% of ImageMagick questions on here are solved by updating the software version and yours is quite out of date, so I was going to test it for you with a newer version.

Comment: I just updated to the latest version of ImageMagick available with homebrew  (6.9.3-6)  and re-tested the command and the file size is the same. Thanks for pointing out that my version was out of date.

Answer (score 1):

ImageMagick writes the subimages of an ICO file as uncompressed BMP images,
so 15kbytes is about what would be expected for your three images, each containing 32-bit RGBA pixels.  You could get a smaller ICO file by removing the transparency.

Comment: This makes sense:  if I convert each file individually from PNG to ICO, the 48x48 png file is exponentially larger than the 32x32 which is exponentially larger than the 16x16 image. Super poor legacy format :'(

Answer (score 1):

This large, unexpected size is due to the ICO format itself, not ImageMagick. For example, [icoutils](http://www.nongnu.org/icoutils/) gives similar results. Warning: [png2ico is reported to produce smaller files but this is only because it doesn't preserve the original pictures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561648/multifile-favicon-ico-much-bigger-than-sum-of-sizes-of-component-files/22594412#22594412).

Instead of focusing on the `favicon.ico` file itself, an effective workaround is to [enable its compression at the HTTP level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561648/multifile-favicon-ico-much-bigger-than-sum-of-sizes-of-component-files/22589277#22589277) (eg. change Apache config to enable the GZip compression of `.ico` files).

Comment: Thanks, I saw your answer on the other issue yesterday after posting this and searching around a bit more (unfortunately my searches didn't turn anything up *before* I posted, sigh).   Good suggestions here. However I'm super disappointed about the ICO sizes.  Browser best practices (e.g. YSlow) dictate a file <2K which is very difficult to achieve with multiple images and an alpha channel.  I've resorted to renaming the `32.png` to favicon.ico and now have a 345 byte file. Hard to beat that, but I haven't tested cross-browser support thoroughly with this solution.

Comment: ^ ... I tried with just two resolutions `16.png` and `32.png`  and that combined down to a 5K file.  :-/

Comment: Yep, I observed similar things too, especially when adding larger sizes (eg. 256x256).