# How to force imagemagick to store PNG inside ICO

Tags: imagemagick

- ImageMagick version: 7.0.10-25 Q16 x86_64
- Environment (Operating system, version and so on): MacOS 10.15.6

When converting a 1.4k (96x96) png to ico, the resulting file is 37k.

```sh
$ magick convert jsiu.dev.black-96.png jsiu.dev.black-96.ico

$ ls -lh
-rw-r--r--  1 js  staff    37K Aug  9 22:19 jsiu.dev.black-96.ico
-rw-r--r--@ 1 js  staff   1.4K Aug  8 17:49 jsiu.dev.black-96.png
```

In comparison: a 3.8k (256x256) png result in a 5.1k ico file.

```sh
-rw-r--r--  1 js  staff   5.1K Aug  8 18:06 jsiu.dev.black-256.ico
-rw-r--r--@ 1 js  staff   3.8K Aug  8 18:05 jsiu.dev.black-256.png
```

Not sure if 1.3k overhead is excessive or not, but at least not 26.4 times in size like the 96x96 version.

After some testing, seems magick always use BMP inside ICO if image is < 256x256. Is there a way to force magick to store PNG inside ICO?

Following is 96x96 PNG:

[image: 96x96 PNG]

Following is 256x256 PNG:

[image: 256x256 PNG]

Additional test:

```sh
magick jsiu.dev.white-96.png -compress none jsiu.dev.white-96.ico
magick jsiu.dev.white-96.png -compress zip jsiu.dev.white-96.ico
magick jsiu.dev.white-96.png -strip jsiu.dev.white-96.ico
magick jsiu.dev.white-96.png -define png:color-type=6 jsiu.dev.white-96.ico
```

They all give same size:

```sh
-rw-r--r--  1 js  staff  38078 Aug 12 04:52 jsiu.dev.white-96.ico
```

Comment: `magick convert ...` is nearly always wrong unless you specifically know you need to run v7 but with v6 behaviour. Generally, we normal users should just use the latest/greatest v7 behaviour with `magick INPUT [OPERATIONS] OUTPUT` omitting the word `convert` altogether.

Comment: This refers... https://stackoverflow.com/a/36135707/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell I tried with and without `convert` give exact same result.

Comment: @MarkSetchell added additional test result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't receive any positive feedback so I end up creating my own command line tool using golang. It creates ico file with png without doing any transformation,

https://github.com/J-Siu/go-png2ico